# File manager opening screen has changed

Tags: files

In my Ubuntu 18.04.5 installation, suddenly the left-hand panel of file manager (Files) has disappeared, and I can't find how to get it back again.  This panel showed, in particular, "Other Locations" which only appears in a new (target) window if I try to copy or move some file(s).  Is there a trick I have forgotten for getting this panel to appear on the opening screen of the file manager?  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ubuntu 18.04 and 18.10, you will need to use the Terminal to fix this...

1. Open the Terminal
2. Enter the following command and press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

   ```
   gsettings reset org.gnome.nautilus.window-state start-with-sidebar
   ```
3. If this does not work, use the following command and press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.window-state start-with-sidebar true
   ```

In Ubuntu 20.04 and newer, this can be fixed using the GUI...

1. Open the File browser (Nautilus)
2. Click on the "Hamburger" menu at the right of the header bar.
3. Select Preferences
4. On the "Views" tab, make sure "Show sidebar" is selected.[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but there is no Preferences item listed in the hamburger menu.  I see only Undo, Redo, Visible columns, Show hidden files, and Reload.  Maybe I am not using Nautilus.  There is no name in the title bar at top, and hovering over the icon on the desktop reveals only "Files".

Comment: I see you are on 18.04. The Preferences dialog is found by clicking on Files in the Top Bar in this version of Ubuntu. However, the Files Preferences dialog in 18.04 does not have the option to show the side bar. I will update my answer to include a solution that will work with your version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks very much!  The first command fixed it, so I didn't have to try the second one.  Thanks again!